# rake aborted! with monit

Tags: ruby, rake, monit

I'm using monit 0.4.1 in ubuntu 9.04. I tried to create a simple rake task just to start the monit service, but it turns out with rake aborted!. Here is my rake script:

```
namespace :monit do
  desc "start monit"
  task :start do
    raise 'This Rake task must be run as root' unless Process.uid == 0

    sh "sudo /etc/init.d/monit start"
  end
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is it failing because the task is running `sh "sudo /etc/init.d/monit start"` as root user, invoked with `sudo rake monit:start`? (essentially running `sudo sudo /etc/init.d/monit start`)

Comment: I tried to change to sh "/etc/init.d/monit start", it still doesn't work. When I run "sudo /etc/init.d/monit start" from my terminal, it works fine except from the rake script.

Comment: It founds out fine in Ubuntu 10.4 with monit 5.0.3.

Comment: Try running the rake task with `--trace` and post the output.

Comment: Thanks. It's better to upgrade monit.